# How to redirect using ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I have button onto click,its takes the input values and redirect to another page in javascript which something looks like this `window.location = "Action Param1=value1&Param2=Value2"`. But the method uses query string which i want to avoid.
So i thought of using ajax

```
   ` $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/MyController/MyAction",
            data: '{Param1:"value1",Param2:"value2"}',
            contentType: "application/json,charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
            }
        });`
```

This does call the controller but does not return anything.
I don't know what i am doing wrong here, a working code would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: You could populate a form with the data and set the form's `action` attribute to the page you want to redirect to.  Otherwise just post with Ajax and then in the success handler `window.location.href = "the-other-url"`

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **SAME** page. If you want to redirect DO NOT use ajax! Just make a normal submit and save yourself writing a pointless script

Answer (score 0):

if it ony include redirect to the page

```
return JavaScript("window.location = 'http:yourlink'");
```

is best option but you want pass the data so do as follows

```
function redi() {
        var date = new Date(); 
        var link = '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Home")';  var args = {
            param1: date.toISOString(),  
            param2: date.toISOString(),
            param3: 'yourdata'
        }; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: link, 
            data: args, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                window.location.href = data.redirecturl; 

            },
            error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown + " " + httpRequest);
            }
        });

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ActionMethod(DateTime param1, DateTime param2, string param3)
    {
        return Json(new { redirecturl = "http:yourlink" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```